# I am trying to create a vb script to highlight duplicate rows in excel file.

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a vb script to highlight duplicate rows in excel file.

Example:

```
Firstname       Lastname
------------------------
Jack            Smith
Jack            Smith
Jack            Johnson
```

I only want the two rows `Jack Smith` highlighted and not the `Jack Johnson` row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a [conditional format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) for that. First add another column with a formula

```
=A2&B2
```

or (more generic)

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())&" "&INDIRECT("B"&ROW())
```

and fill the column with it. Next select all cells in the sheet and add a new conditional formatting rule with a formula looking like this:

```
=COUNTIF($C:$C; INDIRECT("C"&ROW()))>1
```

and choose a format.

Adjust the column identifiers ("A", "B" and "C") as necessary.